# How to partially hide big file names in Thunar?

Tags: xfce, file-manager, thunar

Is it possible to hide filenames that are too big in Thunar? As for now, they stretch the row to fit their names, like in the image:
[image: Thunar file manager]

It not only wastes too much space, but also makes harder to navigate the folder. Is it possible to hide parts of these filenames? Most file managers would show something like "Big File Name Big File Name Big Fil(...)" without changing the original name, of course.